# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object '9479252c-eda1-40a1-a44d-1ae34af76c1c' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using ReactJS in my Chat App, but there's an error while uploading/sending an image to the another contact but it still being sent and I got an error that the Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object '9479252c-eda1-40a1-a44d-1ae34af76c1c' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found). Where did I got an error and how can I solve it?
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuaL4.png)

here's my code for Message.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { ChatContext } from "../context/ChatContext";

const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data } = useContext(ChatContext);

  
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={`message ${message.senderId === currentUser.uid && "owner"}`}
    >
      <div className="messageInfo">
        <img
          src={
            message.senderId === currentUser.uid
              ? currentUser.photoURL
              : data.user.photoURL
          }
          alt=""
        />
       
      </div>
      <div className="messageContent">
        <p>{message.text}</p>
        {message.img && <img src={message.img} alt="" />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Message;
```